# smooth drawing in iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, drawing, line, smoothing

I want to draw line in my drawing application.
I want to draw line as pre the below image show.

[image]

Here you can see that on top and bottom side the line width more than the middle line.
As per the app when user draw slowly the line width is need to increse and when user draw fast the line width is decrease.

I have try http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

but it is reverse of my need.

Can ony have any idea about this kind of smooth drawing?

Comment: Dose any one know any paid or free API to draw smooth like the above image

Answer (score 0):

I see a piece of code in the example link you have given

```
- (float)extractSize:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
    // 1
    float vel = ccpLength([panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view]);
    float size = vel / 166.0f;
    size = clampf(size, 1, 40);
 
    // 2
    if ([velocities count] > 1) {
        size = size * 0.2f + [[velocities objectAtIndex:[velocities count] - 1] floatValue] * 0.8f;
    }
    [velocities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:size]];
    return size;
}
```

Can you try ? replacing it with ...

```
- (float)extractSize:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
    // 1
    float vel = ccpLength([panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view]);
    float size = vel / 166.0f;
    size = clampf(size, 1, 40);
     
    // 2
    if ([velocities count] > 1) {
        size = size * 1.2f + [[velocities objectAtIndex:[velocities count] - 1] floatValue] * 0.8f;
    }
    [velocities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:size]];
    return size;
}
```

**EDIT**: Anyhow, playing with this method should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add Code

```
size = 40 - size;
```

As below code To make exactly reverse.

```
- (float)extractSize:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
  //! result of trial & error
  float vel = ccpLength([panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view]);

  float size = vel / 166.0f;

  size = clampf(size/2, 1, 20);

  if ([velocities count] > 1) {
    size = size * 0.2f + [[velocities objectAtIndex:[velocities count] - 1] floatValue] * 0.8f;
  }
  [velocities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:size]];
  return size;
}
```

Comment: Replace below code                                                                 

 size = clampf(size, 1, 40);

  ////Add below line/////
    size = 40 - size;


with this

size = clampf(size/2, 1, 20);

As, I made change to above code. This worked for me hope it help you as well.